# Stack Overflow activity notification

Tags: discussion, user-interface, notifications

I want to know that **[www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)** has any notification section where I can see who liked my question & answers, bookmarked answers?

Comment: I believe they're using a websocket to update notifications and new activity.

Comment: There is no "liking" on Stack Overflow. And no, upvoting is not the same as "liking". When you upvote a post, you are telling others that the post is of high quality; that it is useful; if it is a question, that it shows research effort and is clear.

Answer (score -2):

In the top right corner of the (desktop) website, there is an icon that looks like a pull out drawer, or a paper tray. 4th icon along from the right.

That is your notification panel. If anyone comments, answers or accepts your answer, that's where you'll know about it. It'll have an indicator on it showing how many notifications you have that you are yet to see.

You cannot see who upvotes or bookmarks your question or answer, and you won't get notifications when either of these things happen. The only way you can track likes is by manually checking your questions.

Comment: Information about bookmarks is public, and can be searched via [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) with the right query (which I don't have offhand, but someone probably does).

Comment: There is nothing called "likes" on Stack Overflow, I assume the OP means upvotes. You do get notifications when someone upvotes your post in the form of a notification that your reputation increased. This notification is shown on the achievements button, right next to the notification button.